# ngrx/store/store"' has no exported member 'select'

Tags: angular, ngrx

when I migrated from the old version to ngrx 4.4.1 and did as told in the migration guide

```
import { Store, compose, select } from '@ngrx/store';
```

I get this error:

```
node_modules/@ngrx/store/store"' has no exported member 'select'
```

Why is he looking inside @ngrx/store/store ? it should be just @ngrx/store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The example reflects what's in master, which will be
>   in the next major release.

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/686